# Page number consistency

Tags: memoir, page-numbering, titles, front-matter

I am working with a book using `memoir` class. My question involves the page numbering of the `\frontmatter` portion of the document. I am under the impression that the frontmatter should be consistently numbered. For instance, if the title page is on `page ii` then why is the next frontmatter page with text `page i` and not `page v`. I was under the impression that page numbering never skips unless called for. My publisher requires that all pages have a number (whether shown or not)

I would be willing to simply supress numbering and reset the page counter to the appropriate number on the copyright page, but that solution seems inelegant or improper for TeX.

And for complete context, the first text page in the frontmatter is my copyright page. Here is my `MWE:`

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}


%   Title Page
\newlength\drop
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\titleGM}{\begingroup% Gentle Madness
\drop = 0.1\textheight
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\vfill
\hbox{%
\hspace*{0.2\textwidth}%
\rule{1pt}{\textheight}
\hspace*{0.05\textwidth}%
\parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{
\vbox{%
\vspace{\drop}
{\noindent\HUGE\bfseries Guide to the\\[0.5\baselineskip]
Blah and Blah}\\[2\baselineskip]
{\Large\itshape Upper Level}\\[4\baselineskip]
{\Large The Author}\par
\vspace{0.5\textheight}
{\noindent Blah Blah Blah, 2013}\\[\baselineskip]
}% end of vbox
}% end of parbox
}% end of hbox
\vfill
\null
\endgroup}
\makeatother                
%       Footer             
\makeevenfoot{ruled}
{}{Copyright \copyright \hspace{0.2em} }{\thepage} 
\makeoddfoot{ruled}
{\thepage}{Copyright \copyright \hspace{0.2em} }{}

%   Docuemnt
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{titlingpage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\titleGM
\end{titlingpage}

\newpage
\pagestyle{ruled}
\lipsum[2]
\clearpage

\mainmatter
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Subsidiary questions (maybe separate question) Why doublepage cleared after title page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `titlingpage` environment resets the page number. If you don't want it, then use the `titlingpage*` environment.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}


%   Title Page
\newcommand*{\titleGM}{% Gentle Madness
  \noindent\hspace*{0.2\textwidth}%
  \rule{1pt}{\textheight}\kern-1pt % compensate
  \hspace*{0.05\textwidth}%
  \parbox[b][\textheight][s]{0.75\textwidth}{
    \vspace{2\baselineskip}
    {\linespread{1.3}\HUGE\bfseries Guide to the\\
     Blah and Blah\par}
    \vspace{2\baselineskip}
    {\Large\itshape Upper Level\par}
    \vspace{4\baselineskip}
    {\Large The Author\par}
    \vfill
    Blah Blah Blah, 2013\par
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
  }% end of parbox
}

%       Footer             
\makeevenfoot{ruled}
{}{Copyright \copyright \hspace{0.2em} }{\thepage} 
\makeoddfoot{ruled}
{\thepage}{Copyright \copyright \hspace{0.2em} }{}

%   Document
\pagestyle{ruled}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{titlingpage*}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\titleGM
\csname @twosidefalse\endcsname
\end{titlingpage*}

\lipsum[2]


\mainmatter
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Here I have shown also how to print something on the verso of the title page. The definition of `\titleGM` has been streamlined to get a better control of what goes where. In your definition you had too long material on the titling page, which triggered a page break.

Comment: Perhaps I don't have the updated package, but `titlingpage*` spits out an undefined error.

Comment: @Calhistorian From `memoir.dtx`: `\changes{v3.6k}{2012/12/24}{Added \Lenv{titlingpage*} env}`. It's not an old update, but not a recent one, either.

Comment: I have begun downloading Texlive 2013. I work on a Mac and it suggestions downloading all of MacTeX. All 2GB's.. Should be a minute.